# How to obtain values from multiple Combo Boxes

Tags: c#

As the titles suggest I am interested in obtaining the value from 4 combo boxes. All 4 combo boxes are the same in the that they list numbers from 0-9. I would like to take those numbers and assigning them to a single string variable. So for example if users selects (CB1 = 4)(CB2 = 3) (CB3 = 2) (CB4 = 1) I would like to take those selection and assign them to a string variable. Thanks in Advance.

-Nogard

Comment: Is this using WinForms or WPF?

Comment: Are you looking for an efficient method in doing this? Or is there anything wrong with taking the `.SelectedItem` property of each combo box and appending to a string ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using winforms

```
string s"";

  private void combobox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          s = combobox1.Text+ combobox2.Text+ combobox3.Text+ combobox4.Text;
        }

  private void combobox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          s = combobox1.Text+ combobox2.Text+ combobox3.Text+ combobox4.Text;
        }
  private void combobox3_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          s = combobox1.Text+ combobox2.Text+ combobox3.Text+ combobox4.Text;
        }
  private void combobox4_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          s = combobox1.Text+ combobox2.Text+ combobox3.Text+ combobox4.Text;
        }
```

or call only a selected index change event in all comboboxes since all are doing same

Comment: I would definitely create and use one function to do the string concatenation.